# Android Firebase: The user remains not verified, when using a dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-protection, firebase-dynamic-links

My task requires of me to ask an account verification inside the App, so I use `sendEmailVerification` with `ActionCodeSettings` as fallowed:

```
ActionCodeSettings settings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                .setAndroidPackageName("***", false, null)
                .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                .setUrl(url)
                .build();
...
user.sendEmailVerification(settings)...
```

Then I get the dynamic link:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent()).addOnSuccessListener
```

All works as it should, but when I check if the user is verified:

```
user.reload().addOnCompleteListener(task -> if (user.isEmailVerified())...)
```

it returns `false`. Am I doing something wrong? Should I somehow set the user as verified manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the dynamic link, you would parse the deep link using FDL library. You then parse the code (oobCode) and call `auth.applyActionCode(actionCode)`. This would complete verification. You can then call `reload()` on the user to pick the changes. Check this documentation for how to do it on web which is similar to Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: Thanks a lot again! I'll try to implement this in my project. I wish, guys from firebase would've described this approach in the Android section of the Guides.

Answer (score 0):

For get correct 'oobCode', when you handle the URL in the App, make sure, that you are decoding URL from UTF-8. Because it has other symbols in the URL query.